# How to make "text-overflow: ellipsis" work on floating divs?

Tags: css

I have two buttons floating to opposite sides of the screen, and I'd like them to collapse nicely if the screen shrinks.  Visually, this is what I want:

```
________________________________________________________________
|                                                               |
|   |LongTextButtonName|                 |LongTextButtonName|   | When the screen
|_______________________________________________________________| is large

_______________________________________
|                                      |
|   |LongTextBu...|  |LongTextBu...|   | When the screen is small
|______________________________________|
```

Unfortunately, right now I get this:

```
________________________________________
|                                       |
|   |LongTextButtonName|                |
|                |LongTextButtonName|   | 
|_______________________________________|
```

I'd like a css-only solution.

Here's my current html and css (and here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UfxgZ/)):

```
<div class="button-container">
  <div class="left-button"><a>LongTextButtonName</a></div>
  <div class="right-button"><a>LongTextButtonName</a></div>
</div>

.button-container {
  min-width:320px;
}
.button-container > div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: orange;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.left-button {
  float: left;
}
.right-button {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fiddle below works based on the following:

- the container requires a width in order to trigger the overflow and ellipsis.
- to allow the boxes continually collapse I have used a percentage width.
- to account for the padding I have used the CSS3 `box-sizing:border-box;`

Note that because of the `box-sizing:border-box;`, this solution will not work on older browsers.

```
.button-container {
  min-width:320px;
}
.button-container > div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: orange;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.left-button {
  float: left;
}
.right-button {
  float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UfxgZ/1/

Comment: That's awesome! There's supposed to be some margin around the buttons, but I'll play around with the percentages to fix that.  What does `box-sizing: border-box` do?

Comment: See updated answer - it accounts for the padding so that the browser sets the width of the container to be 50% minus 16px padding

Comment: Any way to make this work with one of the floated div's shrunk wrapped to it's content? (inline-block display)